# Difference between QueryById() and GetById() in ServiceStack OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Can anyone explain difference between QueryById() and GetById() as they both have same signatures. And there are many common functions which start with Query and Get, there might be some major difference which I think I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OrmLite's **QueryById** and any API starting `Query*` or `Where*` or ending with `*Param` uses  parameterized queries behind-the-scenes, whilst everything else doesn't.

More of this is explained in the documentation on OrmLite's Projects Home Page:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/

Comment: Thanks, what might be the case for non-parametrized queries?

Comment: It's just a matter of taste, and what was originally used since it allowed us to provide a familiar C# **string.Format()** like API, e.g: `db.Select<T>("Fieid = {0}", value)`.

Comment: Aha! c# vs SQL injection :-)

Comment: There is no possible SQL injection, all values are escaped.